# Write largest sum of groups of ranges to a single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Consider the following contrived example, of a range of cells that represent the monthly counts of something over a number of years and a leading summary column, e.g.:

```
.|A    |B      |C    |D    |E    |F    |G    |H    |I    |J    |K    |...
-+-----+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
1|     |Most/3M|Jan19|Feb19|Mar19|Apr19|May19|Jun19|Jul19|Aug19|Sep19|...
2|Foo  |     14|    1|    3|    7|    3|    4|    2|    1|    3|    1|...
3|Bar  |     13|    3|    4|    1|    2|    2|    2|    9|    1|    1|...
4|Baz  |     18|    2|    3|    8|    7|    3|    2|    3|    7|    1|...
```

That summary column in `B:B` represents the highest count for any three-month period, which is calculated *naïvely* using:

```
=MAX(SUM($C2:$E2),SUM($D2:$F2),SUM($E2:$G2),
     SUM($F2:$H2),SUM($G2:$I2),SUM($H2:$J2),
     SUM($I2:$K2))
```

...and then filled down, but this is pretty irritating to have to maintain -- as values get added to the right-most part, e.g, `L:L`, `M:M`, the formula has to be updated with `SUM($J2:$L2)` and `SUM($K2:$M2)`, etc.

One alternative is:

```
={LARGE(($C2:$I2 + $D2:$J2 + $E2:$K2), 1)}
```

...which isn't *quite* so bad, as changing `:$I2` to `:$J2`, `:$J2` to `:$K2` and `:$K2` to `:$L2` is reasonable for a three-month window, and that itself could be derived with horrific use of `INDIRECT`, as per:

```
={LARGE(INDIRECT("R[0]C3:R[0]C"&COUNTA(OFFSET($C2,0,0,1,2000)),FALSE)+
        INDIRECT("R[0]C4:R[0]C"&COUNTA(OFFSET($C2,0,0,1,2000))+1,FALSE)+
        INDIRECT("R[0]C5:R[0]C"&COUNTA(OFFSET($C2,0,0,1,2000))+2,FALSE), 1)}
```

However, this gets painful as the window size increases (i.e. having to add more and more `+` clauses) and/or if the window size is intended to be configurable, e.g. based on the value of `B1` (which is actually just value `3`, with a custom number format of `"Most/"0"M"`)

I did think of possibly either of:

```
={MAX(SUM(OFFSET($C2:$I2,0,0,1,3)))}
={LARGE(SUM(OFFSET($C2:$I2,0,0,1,3)), 1)}
```

...where I would only have to update the range and group size given to `OFFSET`, with the intention to eventually dynamically derive this, e.g. using another horrible `INDIRECT`, such as:

```
=LARGE(SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT("R[0]C3:R[0]C"&
                           (COUNTA(OFFSET($C2,0,0,1,2000))+COLUMN($C:$C)-B$1),
                           FALSE),
                  0,0,1,B$1)),
       1)
```

When using *Evaluate Formula* to step through the above monstrosity in *normal* form, I find that it does indeed eventually resolve down to:

```
=LARGE(SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT("R[0]C3:R[0]C"&(9+3-B$1),FALSE),0,0,1,3)),1)
=LARGE(SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT("R[0]C3:R[0]C"&(12-3),FALSE),0,0,1,3)),1)
=LARGE(SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT("R[0]C3:R[0]C9",FALSE),0,0,1,3)),1)
=LARGE(SUM(OFFSET($C$2:$I$2,0,0,1,3)),1)
=LARGE(SUM($C$2:$E$2),1)
=LARGE(11,1)
=11
```

...so it appears that the range given to `OFFSET` is not expanded as an array and the top-left cell of that range is used directly by `OFFSET` instead.

In *array* form (i.e. <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>), it instead eventually resolves down to:

```
=LARGE(SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT("R[0]C3:R[0]C"&(9+{3}-B$1),FALSE),0,0,1,B$1)),1)
=LARGE(SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT("R[0]C3:R[0]C"&({12}-3),FALSE),0,0,1,B$1)),1)
=LARGE(SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT({"R[0]C3:R[0]C9"},FALSE),0,0,1,B$1)),1)
=LARGE(SUM(OFFSET({#VALUE!},0,0,1,B$1)),1)
=LARGE(SUM(OFFSET({#VALUE!},0,0,1,3)),1)
=LARGE(SUM({#VALUE!}),1)
=LARGE(1,1)
=1
```

...so it appears that array-expansion happens too early (i.e. to result of `COLUMNS($C:$C)`) which later busts the `INDIRECT` call.

(Both `LARGE` and `MAX` result in the same values -- I was using `LARGE` because its documentation suggests that it expects an array, while `MAX` expects an unbounded parameter list of single values.)

Given preferences not to use VBA or change the sheet layout, are there:

1. any tricks to *force* an array expansion in the right place, such that the `SUM(OFFSET)` emits an array that can be used by `LARGE`?
2. any alternative approaches to mine, which require zero-to-miminal amendment of the formulae, as data is added to the right-hand of the sheet?

*(PS. I'm using Excel 2019, not O365/Insiders, so I don't have the dynamic arrays/`SEQUENCE` stuff yet, which looks like it might become relevant.  Answers that rely on that may be useful for posterity, but won't fix my immediate need...)*

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest following method to get the SUM of any 3 Quarters are highest in the year, comprises Helper Data and SUM Large 3 Quarter's value.*

[image]

---

**How it works:**

- Put dates of related months in `Row 1` & apply cell format `mmm-yy`.
- Insert Quarter's name in Rnage `T9:T12`.
- Formula in Cell `U9`, fill it down.

  ```
  =IF(ROW(A1)>=5,"",(SUMPRODUCT((ROUNDUP(MONTH(T$1:AE$1)/3,0)=ROW(A1))*(T$2:AE$2))))
  ```

**N.B.**

- `ROUNDUP(MONTH(T$1:AE$1)/3,0)=Row(A1)` returns `1` and `0s`, `1` is when the Month belongs to *Q1* and `0` when does not and so on for other Quarters like `2`, `3` & `4`.
- `SUMPRODUCT`,  processes all these ranges of data without batting an eyelid.
- `=ROW(A1))` returns 1, represents `Q1` and so down `2, 3 & 4`.
- `=IF(ROW(A1)>=5,""` returns `Blank` when the formula unable to get the Quarter's value after 4.

*After getting data for each Quarter now enter formula in cell `U14` to SUM 3 largest values.*

`{=SUM(LARGE(U$9:U$12,{1,2,3}))}`

**N.B.**

- Better use formula in array (CSE) form so need to finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, otherwise it also works as an non-array formula.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*